# Herstein algebra section 4 problem 16 seems not correct in part a

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $S$ be an infinite set and let $M \subset A(S)$ be the set of all elements $f \in A(S)$ such that $f(s)=s$ for at most a finite number of $s \in S$. Prove that:
>
> (a) $f,g \in M \implies  fg \in M$.
>
> (b) $f \in M \implies f^{-1}\in M$.

First from very definition of $f$, the identity cannot be an element of $M$ since the identity function $i (s) =s \forall s \in A(S)$, thus there is no finite number öf exceptions for identity mapping making $i \in M$,

That means for $f , g \in M$, $fg$ cannot be element of M when $g=f^{-1}$.

Thus (a) part collaps.

What do you think about this?

Comment: in which chapter?

Comment: Most likely this is a typo in the book or a transcription error on your part.  The standard version is "$f(s) \ne s$ for only a finite number of $s$", in other words "$f(s) = s$ for all _but_ a finite number of $s$".

Comment: You até Righteous about  "f(s)≠s  it is so in my text as well a tipo in my question but it still sounds not correct for (a)

Answer (score 1):

The argument for the failure of (a) is sound, but only when you have proved (b).

For (b), prove that there is a bijection between the set of elements moved by $f$ and the set of elements moved by $f^{-1}$.

On the other hand the statement is true if $M$ is the set of maps such that
$$
\text{$f(s)\ne s$ for at most a finite number of $s\in S$}
$$
so check carefully the statement.

Comment: For any f , We see  inverse f is in M I think We do not need to prove b

Comment: @Tayfun That's *precisely* part (b), isn't it?

Comment: For any f , We see  inverse f is in M I think We do not need to prove b We May take any g € M putting those finete number of s € S which satisfies f(s)≠s, in  reversing that's for example if f (s1)=s5 construct g having g (s5) =s1 for all those mappings f(s)≠s, obviously we construct an element g of M since g conforms the definition of M so both g and f € M but gf or fg not element of M. It stems form the fact that identity Function is Not included in M, you verify identity function cannot be element of M because it maps all s to s. I (s)=s cannot be in M ?..